# Is there a way to change an entity category depending on an other entity of the analysed string?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I got this kind of sentence :

---

"I want to go to the japanese restaurant to buy sushis"

intent => go shopping

entity 1 =>@shop => japanese restaurant

entity 2 =>@food => sushis

---

"I want to go to the phone store to buy a Nokia3310"

intent => go shopping

entity 1 =>@shop => phone store

entity 2 =>@phone => Nokia3310

---

As you can see, I would like my second entity to depend on my first entity. So I could use a composite entity so the second entity could be a phone, or a good, or anything actually.... But, then I am not sure it will recognize an entity that makes sense.

for instance :

---

"Wow! Those sushis were nice, now I have to go to the phone store to buy a Nokia3310"

I could get :

intent => go shopping

entity 1 =>@shop => phone store

entity 2 =>@phone => Nokia3310

---

but I also could get

---

intent => go shopping

entity 1 =>@shop => phone store

entity 2 =>@food => sushis

---

and that does not make sense at all...

Is there a way to first check the intent and entities like i first did, and then, when I get :

---

intent => go shopping

entity 1 => @shop => phone store

entity 2 => @food => sushis

---

I just check if it makes sense, and if it does not, I send it back to dialogflow just to ask it to find a @phone in the String?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: In your example, it isn't clear how your second intent "depends on" your first intent. They both sound like the same Intent, just with different parameters. Am I missing something? Are you willing to do this with webhook fulfillment, or do you need to do this completely in Dialogflow?

Comment: You are completely right! I was talking about entities and not intent. I edit this right now.

Comment: That is much clearer. Are you willing to do this with a webhook, or do you want to do this completely inside Dialogflow?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my inattention, and thanks for pointing the mistake. 

I don't really care... If I can do it without webhook, it is cool, if I need webhook it is still ok.